# How to change the Location (x,y) of the object by using coding in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I Want to say sorry if there was a same question like i had. I have tried to Search but i couldn't find it, so.. i hope there is no other question like this..

To the point, i need your help to tell me how to change the Location of an object in a form

What i want to do is making the Button1 move to the left when i press the left key on the keyboard. But i have a problem with how to set the location (x,y) of the object

```
 Private Sub Button1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Button1.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = Keys.Left Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Solution**

Here's a way to accomplish it so that it moves while holding down the key. Create a project with a Form and Button.

Right-click on the Project in the Solution Explorer and add two .NET References:

- PresentationCore
- WindowsBase

Here's the code. A timer will capture key events and move the button:

```
Imports System.Windows.Input

Public Class Form1
    Private timex As New Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        AddHandler timex.Tick, AddressOf myTickEvent
        timex.Enabled = True
        timex.Interval = 100
    End Sub
    Private Sub myTickEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If isKeyPressed(Key.Left) Then
            Me.Button1.Left -= 10
        End If
        If isKeyPressed(Key.Right) Then
            Me.Button1.Left += 10
        End If
        If isKeyPressed(Key.Up) Then
            Me.Button1.Top -= 10
        End If
        If isKeyPressed(Key.Down) Then
            Me.Button1.Top += 10
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Function isKeyPressed(ByRef keys As System.Windows.Input.Key)
        If (Windows.Input.Keyboard.GetKeyStates(keys) And Windows.Input.KeyStates.Down) > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: it works. Thanks

But, The button only will move after i press the key.. so, how to make it move while i pressing the key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, the arrow keys are not captured by the control's KeyPress, KeyDown or KeyUp events. You can make them be captured by KeyDown and KeyUp by setting e.IsInputKey to True in the PreviewKeyDown event. Then you can move the button sideways by changing its Left property. The following assumes the button has focus.

```
Private Sub Button1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) _
  Handles Button1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then e.IsInputKey = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) _
  Handles Button1.KeyDown
    Dim myButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then myButton.Left -= 1
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then myButton.Left += 1
End Sub
```